# How to make constant gap between two dynamic text in jlabel ?(see image)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

[image]

Path part may be longer or shorter that but locked must be in static position

Comment: What should happen when you resize ? If you just want that the text takes all available extra space and the locked keeps using the same space, you could use a `BorderLayout`. `CENTER` for the text (perhaps wrapped in an extra panel with `FlowLayout#LEFT`), `EAST` for the label

Comment: When not resizable, the above outlined solution should work

Comment: @Robin can you give me code do that

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure whether I understood the requirement completely. As I understood it, the following should do the trick

```
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame testFrame = new JFrame( "TestFrame" );
        JPanel contents = new JPanel( new BorderLayout(  ) );

        contents.add( new JLabel( "Locked" ), BorderLayout.EAST );

        JPanel textPanel = new JPanel( new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.LEFT ) );
        textPanel.add( new JLabel( "C:\\Users\\Pictures\\Sample pictures\\Chrysanthemum.jpg ") );

        contents.add( textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );

        testFrame.setContentPane( contents );
        testFrame.pack();
        testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        testFrame.setVisible( true );
      }
    } );
  }
```

Due to the `testFrame.pack()` call, both labels stick together. However, if you manually resize you will see that the `locked` label remains at the right while the URI gets all available space.

Comment: for draggable whatever from JList is possible to use NavigationFilter.Bias or by Html

Comment: is there away to do that by using labelUI ?